# flickering svg group on :hover?

Tags: html, css

When hovering over my svg I'm trying to get the "HI" svg group to disappear and reveal the "BYE" shape.  Instead it flickers between the two groups rapidly - I'm not sure if I messed up the grouping or something but help would be appreciated.

```css
        svg { height: 30vw; display: block; margin: auto;}

        .section:hover #bye.show { display: block; }
        .section:hover #hi.hide { display: none; }
```

```html
<body>       

    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 360 360">

        <a class="section" xlink:href="https://google.com" target="_blank">         
            <g id="bye" class="show">
                <g>
                <rect x="48.685" y="51.107" fill="#00AEEF" width="262.63" height="257.785"/>                    
                <path d="M154.537,168.045c1.444-0.304,3.723-0.531,6.041-0.531c3.306,0,5.433,0.569,7.029,1.861
                    c1.33,0.988,2.128,2.508,2.128,4.521c0,2.47-1.634,4.635-4.332,5.623v0.076c2.432,0.607,5.281,2.621,5.281,6.421
                    c0,2.204-0.874,3.875-2.166,5.129c-1.786,1.634-4.673,2.394-8.853,2.394c-2.279,0-4.027-0.151-5.129-0.304V168.045z M157.842,178.531h3.002c3.495,0,5.547-1.823,5.547-4.293c0-3.002-2.28-4.18-5.623-4.18c-1.52,0-2.394,0.114-2.926,0.229V178.531z M157.842,190.804c0.646,0.114,1.596,0.152,2.774,0.152c3.419,0,6.573-1.254,6.573-4.978c0-3.495-3.001-4.939-6.611-4.939h-2.736
                    V190.804z M180.262,193.312v-10.866l-8.093-14.742h3.761l3.609,7.067c0.988,1.938,1.748,3.495,2.546,5.281h0.076
                    c0.722-1.672,1.596-3.344,2.583-5.281l3.686-7.067h3.762l-8.587,14.704v10.904H180.262z M208.114,181.306h-9.954v9.232h11.094v2.773h-14.399v-25.608h13.83v2.773H198.16v8.093h9.954V181.306z"/>  
                </g>
            </g>
        </a>

        <a class="section" xlink:href="https://google.com" target="_blank">
            <g id="hi" class="hide">
                <g>
                <rect x="48.685" y="51.107" fill="#ED1C24" width="262.63" height="257.785"/>                
                <path d="M170.42,167.703v10.715h12.387v-10.715h3.343v25.608h-3.343v-12.006H170.42v12.006h-3.305v-25.608H170.42z"/>
                <path d="M195.196,167.703v25.608h-3.306v-25.608H195.196z"/>  
                </g>                  
            </g>
        </a>
    </svg>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep only on hover and apply it on the svg instead of the `.section`

```css
svg {
  height: 30vw;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

svg:hover #hi.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 360 360">

        <a class="section" xlink:href="https://google.com" target="_blank">         
            <g id="bye" class="show">
                <g>
                <rect x="48.685" y="51.107" fill="#00AEEF" width="262.63" height="257.785"/>                    
                <path d="M154.537,168.045c1.444-0.304,3.723-0.531,6.041-0.531c3.306,0,5.433,0.569,7.029,1.861
                    c1.33,0.988,2.128,2.508,2.128,4.521c0,2.47-1.634,4.635-4.332,5.623v0.076c2.432,0.607,5.281,2.621,5.281,6.421
                    c0,2.204-0.874,3.875-2.166,5.129c-1.786,1.634-4.673,2.394-8.853,2.394c-2.279,0-4.027-0.151-5.129-0.304V168.045z M157.842,178.531h3.002c3.495,0,5.547-1.823,5.547-4.293c0-3.002-2.28-4.18-5.623-4.18c-1.52,0-2.394,0.114-2.926,0.229V178.531z M157.842,190.804c0.646,0.114,1.596,0.152,2.774,0.152c3.419,0,6.573-1.254,6.573-4.978c0-3.495-3.001-4.939-6.611-4.939h-2.736
                    V190.804z M180.262,193.312v-10.866l-8.093-14.742h3.761l3.609,7.067c0.988,1.938,1.748,3.495,2.546,5.281h0.076
                    c0.722-1.672,1.596-3.344,2.583-5.281l3.686-7.067h3.762l-8.587,14.704v10.904H180.262z M208.114,181.306h-9.954v9.232h11.094v2.773h-14.399v-25.608h13.83v2.773H198.16v8.093h9.954V181.306z"/>  
                </g>
            </g>
        </a>

        <a class="section" xlink:href="https://google.com" target="_blank">
            <g id="hi" class="hide">
                <g>
                <rect x="48.685" y="51.107" fill="#ED1C24" width="262.63" height="257.785"/>                
                <path d="M170.42,167.703v10.715h12.387v-10.715h3.343v25.608h-3.343v-12.006H170.42v12.006h-3.305v-25.608H170.42z"/>
                <path d="M195.196,167.703v25.608h-3.306v-25.608H195.196z"/>  
                </g>                  
            </g>
        </a>
    </svg>
</body>
```

Comment: So if I have multiple square buttons is there anyway to have them all within the `<svg>` container? or would I have to create a new `<svg>` container for each one...?

Comment: @Mogie no you can keep them inside the same SVG but applying the hover effect directly on them will create the flicker because they will disapear so better keep the hover on the SVG

Answer (score 0):

Got the multiple buttons to work like this

```css
        svg {
            height: 30vw;
            display: block;
            margin: auto;
        }
        
        .show{
            display: none;
        }

        .section:hover #hi.hide {
            display: none;
        } 
        .section:hover #bye.show {
            display: block;
        }   

        .section:hover #red.hide {
            display: none;
        }  
        .section:hover #blue.show {
            display: block;
        }
```

```html
<body>        
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 743 360">
        <g class="section">
            <a xlink:href="https://google.com" target="_blank">         
                <g id="bye" class="show">
                    <g>
                        <rect x="48.685" y="51.107" fill="#00AEEF" width="262.63" height="257.785"/>                                
                        <path d="M154.537,168.045c1.444-0.304,3.723-0.531,6.041-0.531c3.306,0,5.433,0.569,7.029,1.861
                            c1.33,0.988,2.128,2.508,2.128,4.521c0,2.47-1.634,4.635-4.332,5.623v0.076c2.432,0.607,5.281,2.621,5.281,6.421
                            c0,2.204-0.874,3.875-2.166,5.129c-1.786,1.634-4.673,2.394-8.853,2.394c-2.279,0-4.027-0.151-5.129-0.304V168.045z
                                M157.842,178.531h3.002c3.495,0,5.547-1.823,5.547-4.293c0-3.002-2.28-4.18-5.623-4.18c-1.52,0-2.394,0.114-2.926,0.229V178.531z
                                M157.842,190.804c0.646,0.114,1.596,0.152,2.774,0.152c3.419,0,6.573-1.254,6.573-4.978c0-3.495-3.001-4.939-6.611-4.939h-2.736
                            V190.804z"/>
                        <path d="M180.262,193.312v-10.866l-8.093-14.742h3.761l3.609,7.067c0.988,1.938,1.748,3.495,2.546,5.281h0.076
                            c0.722-1.672,1.596-3.344,2.583-5.281l3.686-7.067h3.762l-8.587,14.704v10.904H180.262z"/>
                        <path d="M208.114,181.306h-9.954v9.232h11.094v2.773h-14.399v-25.608h13.83v2.773H198.16v8.093h9.954V181.306z"/>
                            
                    </g>
                </g>
            </a>       
            <a xlink:href="https://google.com" target="_blank">
                <g id="hi" class="hide">
                    <g>
                        <rect x="48.685" y="51.107" fill="#ED1C24" width="262.63" height="257.785"/>                            
                        <path d="M170.42,167.703v10.715h12.387v-10.715h3.343v25.608h-3.343v-12.006H170.42v12.006h-3.305v-25.608H170.42z"/>
                        <path d="M195.196,167.703v25.608h-3.306v-25.608H195.196z"/>                            
                    </g>                  
                </g>
            </a>
        </g>
        <g class="section">
            <a xlink:href="https://google.com" target="_blank">         
                <g id="blue" class="show">
                    <g>
                        <rect x="338.685" y="51.107" fill="#ED1C24" width="262.63" height="257.785"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </a>      
            <a xlink:href="https://google.com" target="_blank">
                <g id="red" class="hide">
                    <g>
                        <rect x="338.685" y="51.107" fill="#00AEEF" width="262.63" height="257.785"/>  
                    </g>                  
                </g>
            </a>
        </g>
    </svg>
</body>
```